# How to run package com.zetcode using DrJava

Tags: java

Im trying to run this code at http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/puzzle/

```
1 error found:
File: /Users/java/PuzzleEx.java  [line: (no source location)]
Error: File is in the wrong directory or is declared part of the wrong package.  Directory name 'java' does not match package name 'zetcode'.
```

Please help, how do I run it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to compile it using javac, then you could run it. However, I'd suggest doing nothing of the sort. Just browsing through the link you provided, I'm seeing some bad practices, and outdated code (not declaring variables as interfaces, stuffing all the classes in one file, etc). Instead of following some third party, potentially outdated, tutorial, take a look at the official tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Not only are the official tutorials always up to date, but they're also laid out in easy-to-follow trails and paths.

Edit:
Also, the reason it's not working is exactly as the error says: it's in a different folder than its package is declared to be. If you don't know what a package is, please take a step back and learn the basics first.